# Dropwizard logfile naming

Tags: dropwizard

i'm using Dropwizard for a while now and looking to configure my logging.

As I saw there is no way to configure with log4j.xml file (since dropwizard uses logback) so I decided not to fight this and try to configure via `configuration.yml` file that loads my service.

The config file looks like this:

```
logging:
    level: INFO
    appenders:
    - type: file
      includeCallerData: true
      currentLogFilename: '${LOGS_DIR}/${sys.hostName}-service-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log'
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: '${LOGS_DIR}/${sys.hostName}-service-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log.%i'
      maxFileSize: 10MB
```

And when I run the program I get the following result - inside `${LOGS_DIR}` file named `${sys.hostName}-service-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log`

My initalize function looks like this:

```
@Override  
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ServiceConfig> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new SubtitutingSoruceProvider(new ResourceCongifurationSourceProvider(), new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is correct behavior.
Seems like you missed out on setting the environment variables used in your yml file like `LOGS_DIR` and `sys.hostName`. Dropwizard interpolates the environment variables and if not found, uses the string mentioned and hence logs are generated with directory name `${LOGS_DIR}` and file name as `${sys.hostName}-service-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log`.

Comment: The environment variable works, but the system propert still doesn't, am I missing something with the configuration?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't access system variables in yaml configuration directly. Will update if I come across a solution.